Windows Server 2022 Core DFS Replication issues
I have an AD network with 3 DC. After a migration with a changing PDC emulator we have a problem where SYSVOL and NETLOGON shares are not created.
We have found community manual, a temporary workaround by modifying registry value HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters SysVolReady 0 => 1.
After that we encountered a replication error, where dfsrreplicatedfolderinfo state became 2 (Initial Sync) on newly added DC. So we moved to Microsoft Manual, but were unable to run step DFSRDIAG POLLAD, because Windows Server Core 2022 does not have DFSRDIAG or server feature RSAT-DFS-Mgmt-Con. Get-WindowsFeature RSAT-DFS* returns nothing.
I cannot find information  about RSAT-DFS-Mgmt-Con starting from the early 2020s. Can someone please tell us?

Open a support case with Microsoft.

Oh, they gave us great advice to migrate our domain to Azure to fix the problem and avoid similar issues in the future. And of course, they can help us seamlessly migrate to Azure without problems.

RSAT-DFS-Mgmt-Con does not exist on Windows Server 2022 Core, but DFSRDIAG was found after installing role: DFS Replication FS-DFS-Replication.

Mark your own reply as an answer.

I have a 2 day timer before I can do it. 22h left.

Thank you for confirming MSFT left out this important tool when implementing ADDS on Server Core. And of course, as soon as we install FS-DFS-Replication, AD RAP will complain about "unnecessary features" installed on the DC. How on earth are you supposed to perform MSFT's own documented domain recovery without it?

@LeeM: there's nothing preventing you from uninstalling the feature after it is used so that the reports run clean. Core DCs are rare, and DC DFS corruption even more rare. There's nothing wrong with installing something one off to correct a rare issue, particularly when there is a simple recreate feature on SYSVOL.

Yes, I know that perfectly well; it was really a rhetorical question. Although I do think MSFT should do better - it is a pretty astonishing omission.  I'd just rather have something simple and in-place already. Not yet another thing to add to a recovery procedure. In any case, I'm happy with the WMI method I've outlined in another answer.

While it doesn't fix the astonishing oversight of MSFT omitting the DFSRDiag tool on Server Core (without installing "extra features" on a DC, which MSFT deprecates), here is a method that does work for Server 2022 Core edition (and previous Server versions).
You can call the equivalent of DFSRDIAG POLLAD via WMI, using the PollDsNow method in the DfsrConfig class.
The below shows syntax and output from various WMI tools available on Server 2022 - not all OS versions will have all of these. Invoke-CimMethod is preferred for the most recent OS versions - it returns a PsCustomObject, helpful for scripting purposes. Any method of calling PollDsNow will return value of 0 on success.
Invoke-CimMethod
> Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDfs' -ClassName DfsrConfig -Method PollDsNow

ReturnValue PSComputerName
----------- --------------
          0

Invoke-WmiMethod
> Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDfs' -Path DfsrConfig -Name PollDsNow

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   :

WMIC
> wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoftdfs class DfsrConfig call PollDsNow
Executing (DfsrConfig)->PollDsNow()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 0;
};

The reference I originally found for the PollDSNow method is from a Microsoft article demonstrating a VBScript method of polling AD. I also found the WMIExplorer tool helpful for understanding the available classes and methods in the DFS namespace.
Note: Microsoft generally do NOT recommend using classic DFS methods for managing SYSVOL, so the only method I'm recommending here is PollDsNow. (Clearing Conflict and Deleted also leverages classic DFS methods.)
